# Create a new text field by pressing enter using tiptap extension of vue-cli

Tags: html, editor, vue-cli-3, prose-mirror

I am using tiptap extension that is a rich-text editor for Vue. And I want to create a new text field every time that I press enter. 
But I cannot find the solution to do that. 
Here's the link of tiptap: https://github.com/scrumpy/tiptap.

I tried to use v-on:keyup.

...

```
    template:`
     <div>
       <div v-if='show == true'>
          <button>Hey</button>
       </div>
       <p contenteditable="true" 
          v-on:keyup.enter="newGroup" 
          v-on:keydown.tab="newGroup" >

       Hello world

      </p>
     <div v-if='show'> </div>
  </div>
  `,

...
methods: {
....
newGroup()
    {
      app.divs++;
    }

...
```

I want to create a new text field.